# Заполнение listview информацией из БД с условием

Tags: activity, android, listview, java, sqlite

Здравствуйте. 
Столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Существует 2 активности, обе унаследованы от listactivity и обе заполняются информацией из БД sqlite. При нажатии на элемент списка первой активности должна открываться вторая активность, где в зависимости от выбранного элемента осуществляется заполнение списка. Проблема в том, что когда я пытаюсь это реализовать, у меня ничего не получается. Вторая активность запускается, но список не выстраивается.
Код первой активности:

```
public class FizCatalog extends ListActivity {

private static final String DB_NAME = "yourlex";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "RazdelF";
private static final String RAZDEL_ID = "_id";
private static final String RAZDEL_NAME = "name";
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private ListView listView;
private ArrayList razdel;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fiz_catalog);
    ExternalDbOpenHelper dbOpenHelper = new ExternalDbOpenHelper(this,
            DB_NAME);
    database = dbOpenHelper.openDataBase();
    fillRazdel();
    setUpList();

}

private void fillRazdel() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    razdel = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor razdelCursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {
            RAZDEL_ID, RAZDEL_NAME }, null, null, null, null, RAZDEL_NAME);
    razdelCursor.moveToFirst();
    if (!razdelCursor.isAfterLast()) {
        do {
            String name = razdelCursor.getString(1);
            razdel.add(name);
        } while (razdelCursor.moveToNext());
    }
    razdelCursor.close();
}

private void setUpList() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, razdel));
    OnItemClickListener itemClick = new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            Intent intentF = new Intent();
            intentF.setClass(FizCatalog.this, FizCatRaz.class);
            String itemid = new Integer(position).toString();
            Bundle a = new Bundle();
            a.putString("itemid", itemid);
            intentF.putExtras(a);
            startActivity(intentF);
        }
    };
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(itemClick);

}
```

Код второй активности, который не работает как нужно

```
public class FizCatRaz extends ListActivity {
    private static final String DB_NAME = "yourlex";
    // private final String TABLE_NAME = "";
    private static final String S_ID = "_id";
    private static final String S_NAME = "name";
    private static final String S_ABOUT = "about";
    private static final String S_PRICE = "price";
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayList sf;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sfiz_catalog);
    ExternalDbOpenHelper dbOpenHelper = new ExternalDbOpenHelper(this,
            DB_NAME);
    database = dbOpenHelper.openDataBase();
    fillRazdel();
    setUpList();

}

private void fillRazdel() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Intent intentF = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String fName = intentF.getStringExtra("itemid");
    sf = new ArrayList<String>();
    String fizS = bundle.getString("itemid");
    // НЕ РАБОТАЕТ

    if (fizS == "0") {
        final String TABLE_NAME = "RF_interests";
        Cursor sfcurcor = database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { S_ID,
                S_NAME }, null, null, null, null, S_NAME);
        sfcurcor.moveToFirst();
        if (!sfcurcor.isAfterLast()) {
            do {
                String name = sfcurcor.getString(1);
                sf.add(name);
            } while (sfcurcor.moveToNext());
        }
        sfcurcor.close();
    }
}
private void setUpList() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, sf));
    OnItemClickListener itemClick = new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Вы выбрали " + parent.getItemIdAtPosition(position),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(itemClick);

}
```

Дело в том, что в дальнейшем мне нужно будет сделать так, чтобы вторая активность заполнялась данными той таблицы, которая была вызвана нажатием на элемент из первой активности. Попробовал сделать эту проверку с помощью оператора IF, но в результате вторая активность открывается, но не заполняется. Без оператора IF всё работает, но я не хочу создавать на каждый элемент списка первой активности отдельную активность. 
Что посоветуете?

**UPD**
Внес исправления согласно предлагаемому решению и дописал код.

```
if (fizS.equals("0")) {
            String TABLE_NAME0 = "RF_interests";
            Cursor sfcurcor0 = database.query(TABLE_NAME0, new String[] { S_ID,
                    S_NAME }, null, null, null, null, S_NAME);
            sfcurcor0.moveToFirst();
            if (!sfcurcor0.isAfterLast()) {
                do {
                    String name = sfcurcor0.getString(1);
                    sf.add(name);
                } while (sfcurcor0.moveToNext());

            }
            sfcurcor0.close();
        }
        else if (fizS.equals("1")) {
                String TABLE_NAME1 = "RF_pravdoc";
                Cursor sfcurcor1 = database.query(TABLE_NAME1, new String[] { S_ID,
                        S_NAME }, null, null, null, null, S_NAME);
                sfcurcor1.moveToFirst();
                if (!sfcurcor1.isAfterLast()) {
                    do {
                        String name = sfcurcor1.getString(1);
                        sf.add(name);
                    } while (sfcurcor1.moveToNext());
            }
                sfcurcor1.close();
        }
        else if (fizS.equals("2")) {
                String TABLE_NAME2 = "RF_nedv";
                Cursor sfcurcor2 = database.query(TABLE_NAME2, new String[] { S_ID,
                        S_NAME }, null, null, null, null, S_NAME);
                sfcurcor2.moveToFirst();
                if (!sfcurcor2.isAfterLast()) {
                    do {
                        String name = sfcurcor2.getString(1);
                        sf.add(name);
                    } while (sfcurcor2.moveToNext());
            }
                sfcurcor2.close();
        }
```

При нажатии на первый элемент на первой активности, вторая открывается и всё показывает правильно. Но при нажатии на второй элемент, работа приложения останавливается и в логах пишет следующее:

```
06-16 09:06:01.416: E/AndroidRuntime(1887): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-16 09:06:01.416: E/AndroidRuntime(1887): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.yourlex/com.example.yourlex.FizCatRaz}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: RF_pravdoc (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, name FROM RF_pravdoc ORDER BY name
```

Я так понял, что ругается на то, что якобы нет такой таблицы, однако она есть в базе данных. В чем проблема?

Comment: Не понятно зачем Вы превратили "itemid" в строку, но вот что бросается в глаза:     
     fizS == "0"     - это выражение сравнивает не содержимое строк, а ссылки на них и результат не тот, что Вы ожидаете.       
Используйте методы стринга (equals(), compareTo()) для сравнения.

Comment: думаю задайте новый вопрос, и сформулируйте его по другому

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Может вся проблема в условии, которое вы посылаете оператору **if**

```
//как сравнивать строки    
 fizS == "0" //не правильно  
 fizS.equals("0") // правильно
```

Comment: Не совсем так - интернированные строки сравнивать == можно, а иногда и очень полезно

Comment: при сравнении строковых констант нужно знать тонкости, которые есть в java, не думаю, что это тот случай

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/users/11515/woesss
при сравнении через    
if (fizS == "0")     
то есть через ==

сравниваются указатели на объекты, а не собственно стороки

Comment: @metalurgus тут нюансы есть просто, возможно на первый взгляд не очевидные,  указатели можно сравнивать, и если знать как, то можно добиться того же результата, но чтобы это делать, необходимо понимать, как хранятся строковые константы в памяти Java. Хотя я все такие за equals, чтобы избежать не нужных и глупых ошибок